# Metasyntactic variables: do you use something else than "foo", "bar" according to your mother tongue

Tags: country, metasyntactic-variable

In english, the variables `foo` and `bar` are very often used for simple examples, or for anonymous variables (see these three posts for more on these [metasyntactic variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable) [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163229/code-examples-foo-bar), [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262271/where-did-foo-and-bar-come-from), [(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234507/to-foo-bar-or-not-to-foo-bar-that-is-the-question))

Usually, I often use **`titi`**, **`toto`** and **`huhu`** and it seems that I am not the only french guy to use them.

So, they should be different in german, spanish, chineese or whatever language...

And you, depending on your mother tongue, which variable names do you use (other than `bar` and `foo`, of course) in that case (I mean for anonymous variables, since we all know that we *shouldn't* use them in real program) ?

Comment: This should probably be community wiki.

Comment: How are "foo" and "bar" not programming-related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"thingy" and "thangy" have been showing up in my code over the last six months. no idea how that started. mother-tongue = English.

[below added 24 hours after above]

Hunh. "thingy" shows up in [Wictionary:Metasyntactic words](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Metasyntactic_words) (links to [Wictionary:thingy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikisaurus:thingy)) and briefly in [Wikipedia:Metasyntactic_variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable). And, of course, THIS page now shows up in the top-10 google hits for ["metasyntactic thingy."](http://www.google.com/search?q=metasyntactic+thingy) (I'm just making it worse, aren't I?)

I use it most commonly as a throw-away buffer-name in Emacs

Comment: thingy is used as a parameter in zeroclipboard: http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/downloads/list -- "$: function(thingy) { " etc.

Answer (score 2):

"wibble" was popular in England.
Foo and Bar were always American, I never heard them until the web became widespread.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can only apply to languages using Latin characters (since most programming languages use this character set).

I work in a development company based in Jordan (official language: Arabic), and we use `Foo` and `Bar`.

Comment: most programming languages use Latin characters, but I suppose that programmers can then use a variable that "sounds" like another word/phonem in their original tongue, isn't it ?
Of course, very often the english is used for the variables' name and the comments, but not always (specially with people that are not very confident with their english)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to "foo" and "bar", I also use "blah", "variable", "testvar" and others.